# Get content uri from file path in android for video

Tags: java, android, uri, android-videoview

know the absolute path of a video (say for eg, /sdcard/abcd.mp4). Is there any way to the content URI for this file?

Actually, in my code, I select the image from gallery and trim the video file and save it in the folder but I don't know how to get the content URI

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with a conversion to content uri. You would have to tell which provider to use first.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/sample.jpg"));
```

Comment: That is no "content://" uri. That is a "file://" uri.

Comment: exactly i have file uri i want content uri

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted three times? I dont even get that for a correct answer ;-).